# The recommended way to set up DNS?

Tags: email, dns, smtp, amazon-lightsail

**Brief background:**
I am learning VPC with AWS lightsail(wordpress). I just realised it doesn't come with email service and have to be set up on our own.

**What I want to do:**
I would prefer to use a non Amazon's email service provider (maybe proton or g-suite) for daily email communications.

I'd prefer to have `www.example.com` to be redirected to `example.com`

**My questions:**
What is the recommended way to set up the email MX record?

Does it make any difference in configuring DNS with domain registrar or hosting service provider?

I remember Google Analytics has the option to direct `www.example.com` to `example.com` and vice versa. Is it similar to DNS directing or that is mainly for site traffic direction?

**Extra info**:
Currently, the domain is registered with Namecheap and I have the NS pointed to AWS. I'm open to  any kind of configuration suggestions because it is mainly for learning purpose and can be changed/deleted anytime.

Comment: This is not really a programming question and not so suitable to SO.

Comment: Thanks @GregA.Woods I'll check out other SE to find a suitable one for this question. or do you happen to know one?

Comment: I think serverfault.com would probably be the best.